# Hreflang Tags on Paginated Pages

Tags: seo, hreflang, pagination

I have a question with regards to Hreflang tags on paginated pages. Let's say I have english version and german version website for /blog category

So my URL's will be - [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) - EN version
[www.example.com/de/blog](http://www.example.com/de/blog) - DE version.
enter code here
Now the question is Can I have hreflang tags on paginated pages If my content not matching?

For ex: [www.example.com/page/3](http://www.example.com/page/3) - EN version (have four sections showing blogs)
[www.example.com/de/page/3](http://www.example.com/de/page/3) - (having six sections showing blogs which are other from EN version)

In the above scenario, is it good to have hreflang tags on these paginated pages (if exact content not matching)

Kindly let me know if this okay or not okay to implement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would only use hreflang on the blog pages, but not on the pagination pages in your case. As you already pointed out the pagination pages do not show the same content and therefore would not be a good fit in a language/region targeting. In addition you might have a different number of pagination pages in the different languages so you could not place hreflang on all of them anyway.

Note: All members of an hreflang group need to link to all other pages and a self link needs to be present. Each of the language/region values must be unique within the hreflang group.

Generally the main usage of hreflang is to solve content duplication issues when you have multiple pages with the same language targeting different markets (de-DE, de-AT, de-CH or en-US, en-GB, en-AU), but with two completely different languages this is not the case.